# How to make a step optional with django form wizard

Tags: django, django-formwizard

Django form wizard has a `condition_dict` which allows skipping of certain steps when conditions are met. What if we don't want to skip a step but make it optional. In other words, the form for that step will still be rendered, but it has both a submit button as well as a skip-this-step button. The submit button will carry out normal form validation, where as the skip button will take users to the next step.

Is this even possible with the form wizard in django 1.4/1.5? If so, please give me some pointers. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose a hackish way is to have that "skip" button fill out the form with fake data and in the done() step, that fake data will be recognized and discarded. There's got to be a cleaner approach though.

Answer (score 0):

If you set default values or nullable fields on the form in question, the form clean will pass, setting the form "optional", no?

Comment: That requires defining a separate form class with all fields set with required=False. I'm looking for a form-wizard level solution so that I can use the same form class for other scenarios as well. As of now it looks like it would be a serious tweaking of the process_step method.

Comment: In this case i think you would need to redefine the condition_dict in every form wizard step, associated with the logic you need.